# how to handle content after download it in the in-app purchase?

Tags: ipad, pdf, in-app-purchase

i am working on an app for a magazine, it is simply a PDF reader with in-app purchase.

i can download the new content as a zip file from the server after in-app purchase. but i dont know what to do after that.

how can i handle this downloaded file and display in the PDF Reader?

Comment: Does it can be saved in any directory? or only in Documents? What apples says about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may save it somewhere, ex. to the documents folder.

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

// the path to write file
NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myFile"];

[data writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];